# Difference between oncached and onupdateready

Tags: html

What is the exact difference between oncached and onupdateready methods in AppCache API? It seems like both get fired when the manifest items are downloaded completely. If that's the case, which event get fired first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [oncached](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771704(v=vs.85).aspx) event gets fired when the cache is downloaded for the first time.

The [onupdateready](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj191829(v=vs.85).aspx) event gets fired when the previously cached resources have been updated, typically when an update to the manifest file is detected. This does not automatically update the cache, it just downloads the new resources. The [swapCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465709(v=vs.85).aspx) method should be called to switch the old cache with the newly downloaded one.

From [this link](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JavaScriptAndApplicationCache.html) (emphasis mine):

> window.applicationCache.oncached - This eventhandler is called, after the downloading eventhandler is called, when all the resources in the manifest file have been downloaded. No more eventhandlers are called after this eventhandler.
>
> window.applicationCache.onupdateready - This eventhandler is called, after the downloading eventhandler is called, **when there has been an updated to an existing Application Cache** and all the resources in the manifest file have been downloaded. No more eventhandlers are called after this eventhandler.

Event listeners for each of these events can be added as explained [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/offline-browsing-in-html5-with-applicationcache/).

```
appCache.addEventListener('cached', function(e) {
    // Cache event code
}, false);

appCache.addEventListener('updateready', function (e) {
    appCache.swapCache();
    window.location.reload();
}, false);
```